# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created A database inside visual studio and then add the connections string in my code

```
string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\POS\\App_Data\\POS.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
```

I am getting this exception when I try to fetch data from Database

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +802
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +682
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you have a prentesis in your Data Source=LocalDB)?

try this:

```
string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\POS\\App_Data\\POS.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
```

**Update**
change

```
Data Source= (localdb)\v11.0
```

To

```
Data Source= (localdb)\\v11.0
```